# Parsing DateTime from ExcelSheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datetime

I'm looking for a bit of advice.

I'm writing a class to automatically extract information from an excel spreadsheet (using NPOI api) in C#, and then import this information into a database. I've got it all working fine except for one small issue.

One of the spreadsheets I'm working with, contains the date in the following format: **04/01/2011 04:43:28**.

When I ran the web application, I got the following error message:

> String was not recognised as a valid
>   DateTime

So I debugged through the code after this, and it turns out that the date is being read in as: **40546.0151388889**, so it is being formattted back to a number.

I'm unsure how to overcome this issue and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

Here is an exerpt from my code:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                            HSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

                            HSSFSheet sheet = templateWorkbook.GetSheetAt(w);
                            HSSFRow row = null;


                            for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
                            {
                                FTPSalesDetails t = null;
                                int currentColumn = 0;

                                try
                                {
                                    ModelContainer ctn = new ModelContainer();

                                    row = sheet.GetRow(i);

                                    if (row == null)
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }

                                    t = new FTPSalesDetails
                                    {
                                        RowNumber = i,
                                        InvoiceDate = GetCellValue(row.GetCell(0)),
                                        NetUnitsSold = GetCellValue(row.GetCell(2)),
                                        ProductCode = GetCellValue(row.GetCell(5))
                                    };


                                    int Qty = int.Parse(t.NetUnitsSold);
                                    // Do a Loop for net units sold.
                                    for (int x = 0; x < Qty; x++)
                                    {
                                        ItemSale ts = new ItemSale
                                        {
                                            ItemID = GetItemID(t.ProductCode),
                                            RetailerID = GetRetailerID("Samsung"),
                                            DateSold = DateTime.Parse(t.InvoiceDate),
                                        };

                                        ctn.AddToItemSales(ts);
                                        ctn.SaveChanges();
                                    }
                                }

                                ....


                                private string GetCellValue(HSSFCell cell)
                                {
                                    string ret = null;

                                    if (cell == null)
                                    {
                                        return ret;
                                    }

                                    switch (cell.CellType)
                                    {
                                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                            ret = cell.BooleanCellValue.ToString();
                                            break;
                                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                            ret = cell.NumericCellValue.ToString();
                                            break;
                                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                            ret = cell.StringCellValue;
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    return ret;
                                }
```

Comment: Tags asp.net and Excel together ? check Tags.isnt this a window form ?

Comment: @Sangram, no this isn't a windows form. It's from a class library that I call from my web application. Apologies if the tags are incorrect.

Comment: Ohh..Then my apologies..i hv nt wrked in asp + excel thats y was a bit curious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use DateTime.FromOADate(cellValue)

(you might need to do (cellValue - 1) because of a bug in excel date calculation)

Comment: Which bug,i never faced problem in this ?

Comment: Excel treats 1900 as a leap year so all daynumbers after 1900-02-28 is one day off. I checked it now and FromOADate compensates for the error but gets it wrong on dates before 1900-02-28. (i.e. FromOADate(2) = 1900-01-01 but 2 in Excel is 1900-01-02)

Comment: @Adarianm: Good Information....ideally what u are saying  right..but we rarely use 1900/xx/xx dates nowadays..so it can be spared i guess..

Comment: @adrianm You should add your explanation to the answer :)

Comment: You don't need to subtract 1 day when using `FromOADate(36565)` for modern dates as it compensates it (unless you want to get dates for first 60 days of 1900)

Answer (score 3):

When you try fetching date from Excel.it convert into a specific format.Take this vaue in double and use it like following.

Try:

```
double dateDouble = 40546.0151388889
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(dateDouble);
string dateString = dt.ToString();
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as what adrianm answered 22 mins before?

Comment: dont u think i have put it in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

See [this excellent read](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) about dates and excel:

> Excel stores dates and times as a
>   number representing the number of days
>   since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional
>   portion of a 24 hour day:
>   ddddd.tttttt . This is called a serial
>   date, or serial date-time.